# Calling useQuery conditionally results into build failures

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-hooks

I have a use case, where in the UI i am displaying list of all todos associated with a user. There is a toggle button, toggling which, displays list of only `completed` todos with the same user. I am calling react hook `useQuery` but **conditionally** based on toggle button status. Below is the code:

```
import TodoItems from './TodoItems';
import { LIST_TODOS_BY_USERNAME, LIST_TODOS_BY_STATUS } from '../graphql/queries';
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/react-hooks';

type TodoListProps = {
  username: string;
  showCompleted: boolean;
};

const TodoList:FC<TodoListProps> = ({ username, showCompleted }) => {
  const { loading, error, data } = !showCompleted
    ? useQuery(LIST_TODOS_BY_USERNAME, { variables: { username }, pollInterval: 500 })
    : useQuery(LIST_TODOS_BY_STATUS, { variables: { username, status: 'COMPLETED' }, pollInterval: 500 });

  if (error) {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{`Error! ${error}`}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div className="todoapp">
      <div>
        <header className="header">
          <div className="imagetool">
            <img
              alt={username}
              src={`https://something.com/?uid=${username}`}
            />
          </div>
          <H1>
            {username}
            &rsquo;s todos
          </H1>
          <div className="todo-list-container">
            <Row gridGap={32} justifyContent="center" padding={8}>
              <View>
                {loading ? (
                  <Col alignItems="start" gridGap={16}>
                    <Spinner size={SpinnerSize.Small} />
                  </Col>
                ) : (
                  <TodoItems todoListItems={!showCompleted ? data.getTodosByUserName : data.getTodosByStatus} />
                )}
              </View>
            </Row>
          </div>
        </header>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TodoList;
```

However, this works great but during the build, since linting comes into play, it fails with error:

> *17:7    error    React Hook "useQuery" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks*

How can i remedy the problem without disabling the lint rule?

Any pointers are appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In React hooks need to be called *always* -- hence they should *not* be called only sometimes (=conditionally). That applies even to hooks which use the same hook function (`useQuery()` as in your case). To call the *very same* `useQuery()` on *every* render iteration use *one single* hook; hence

change this

```
  const { loading, error, data } = !showCompleted
    ? useQuery(LIST_TODOS_BY_USERNAME, { variables: { username }, pollInterval: 500 })
    : useQuery(LIST_TODOS_BY_STATUS, { variables: { username, status: 'COMPLETED' }, pollInterval: 500 });
```

to this:

```
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(
    !showCompleted ? LIST_TODOS_BY_USERNAME : LIST_TODOS_BY_STATUS,
    {
      variables: !showCompleted
        ? { username }
        : { username, status: 'COMPLETED' },
      pollInterval: 500,
    }
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use useQuery conditionally. You have two options either get the query as a prop's value or store the name of the query in the state of the component and change it based upon need.